# How Can I Send An Email Directly From An MX Server?

Tags: email, smtp, mail-server, smtp-auth

I am aware there are many questions similar to this. However, being that certain standards and security protocols are constantly evolving, the solutions to this question that were valid just a year ago no longer are.

---

### GOAL :

- I am trying to send an email directly from a mail server (e.g: *smtp.gmail.com*) via the **command line**.
- One of my reasons for wanting to send mail this way is that I need to be able to specify different sender's addresses via the **MAIL FROM:<_______>** field.
- It doesn't even have to be a secure message | **I don't require TLS/SSL** for my purposes, but google's smpt servers require TLS now. Any way around this?

---

### PROBLEM :

- All mail servers I've tried so far has required initiating **STARTTLS**.
- The last time I did this (few years back), the server just let me do everything in plain text, no authorization was required - The interaction I recall having with the server was something like this:

**cmd: (*2017*)**

```
   >> telnet smtp-mx2.gmail.com 25
       <GMAIL SMTP-MX2-SERVER>
   > HELO 
       <250 OK>
   > MAIL FROM:<other_person1@gmail.com>
       <250 <other_person1@gmail.com> Sender ok>
   > RCPT TO:<destination_address@gmail.com>
       <250 <other_person1@gmail.com> Recipient ok>
   > SUBJECT: Some Notice Letter
       <250 "Some Notice Letter" Subject ok
   > DATA
       <354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself>
   > Msg Content line 1
   > Msg Content line 2
   > Msg Content line 3
   > Msg Content line 4
   > .
       <250 OK.. Message is accepted for transmission>
   > quit
       GOODBYE!
   Connection has been lost...
```

- The above worked in 2017, much of the standards/protocols have apparently changed, hence why I need the help.
- Here is what I am doing now based on more recent posts of how others have gotten this to work -  along with the problem I am encountering:

**cmd:**

```
   >> telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
      <220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP g19-20020a67ea13000000b00349dfb48b4asm148524vso.20 - gsmtp>
   > helo ABC
      <250 smtp.gmail.com at your service>
   > STARTTLS
      <220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS>
   > AUTH §♥☺☻☻F

   Connection to host lost.
```

- After **STARTTLS**, if I don't type anything the connection holds. Once I start typing: like I was trying to type: **AUTH LOGIN**, it prints those funny characters after I type *"AUTH"* then connection cuts.

Anyone know of a less difficult mail server I can try this on? I am at a loss..

Here is a python code I even tried it with using the package *smtpllib*, made just for something like this. It still failed

```
import smtplib    

gmail_user = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'
gmail_pwd  = 'xxxxxxx'


sent_from = gmail_user
to = ['myemail_address1@gmail.com', 'myemail_address2@hotmail.com']
subject = 'OMG Test msg'
body = 'Hey, what\'s up?\n\n- You'

email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:
    #server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    print('\tehlo')
    server.starttls()
    print('\tSTARTTLS SUCCESSFUL')
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)    # <------ THIS IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS
    print('\tlogin SUCCESSFUL')
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    print('\tmsg sent SUCCESSFUL!')
    server.close()
    print('\tserver closed SUCCESSFUL')
    print('\nEmail sent!')
except:
    print('Something went wrong...')
```

Any inputs appreciated

Comment: just use a normal scriptable MUA that can do encryption. eg. [mutt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128004/333919) (but gmail will almost certainly still flag that you are spooffing or even refuse the email if you don't "own" the address you are sending from - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370)

Comment: If you try spoofing an email address protected by DMARC/SPF/DKIM it'll probably be refused by the server or flagged as spam by the recipent

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have OpenSSL (or LibreSSL), TLS is not a problem at all. You just cannot do the TLS handshake by hand using `telnet`. My understanding is that you want to *submit* an email to the outgoing mail server of Gmail as a registered user (instead of *relaying* an email from an arbitrary address to the incoming mail server of Gmail). If this is the case, then DMARC/SPF/DKIM won't pose a problem at all because you authenticate to the outgoing mail server and submit the message the way any mail client would. You have two options:

- Implicit TLS on port 465: `openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:465`
- Explicit TLS on port 587: `openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587`

Implicit TLS is the preferred option since [RFC 8314](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8314).

Let me know if you have any issues with the subsequent authentication.

Comment: The reason for my (respectively your) confusion is that you used port 25 in your first example, which is the port for message relay, not submission. (Your first example has many other issues as well. For example, there's no `SUBJECT` SMTP command.)

Comment: On a different note, if you used `EHLO` instead of `HELO` when connecting on port 587 with telnet, you would see that Gmail lists `STARTTLS` as a supported SMTP extension but not `AUTH`. So yes, Gmail enforces that you upgrade your connection to TLS with `STARTTLS` before you can authenticate (so that you don't send your password over an insecure connection).